# How do I filter a textual dropdown using model data

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, filter

G'day all,

Have a problem that I've been mulling over for a bit here - we have a dropdown box in our html/javascript (legacy, no JQuery yet) front end that displays a list of textual elements like so:

- Total capacity < 500ml
- Total capacity 500ml - 1L
- Total capacity 1L - 2L
- Total capacity > 2L

In our Java model, we have the capacity of an item stored - so we know that CokeBottle is 600.00f capacity etc.

My question is, without remodeling the dropdown objects to be more than just strings, how could I best automatically choose the correct capacity for an item when it is selected elsewhere? So that when the page is loaded for CokeBottle, it knows to choose "Total capacity 500ml - 1L" by default?

Regular expressions would be one way of doing this, but it seems brittle and a bit confusing to maintain going forward.

Thoughts?

EDIT: I'm also happy to consider a filter approach - removing those items that dont qualify, as sometimes we will have up to twenty elements in these dropdowns - so anything we can do to reduce the manual work of a user will be welcome.

Comment: I haven't done this before but a good way would be to add data-capacity to your option element. Since you're not planning on re designing the control that generates html for the select you could use a regexp on the option value, seems like getting the first number will do.

Comment: Why the Java tag? What's this got to do with Java?

Comment: It's the model that backs it; but fair call, i'll remove the tag... edit: or not, as thats too minor an edit to the question.

Comment: @f1dave The dropdown containing the capacities, is it always a fixed amount of items or dynamic in items?

Comment: @HMR good question... It actually varies in some cases, but for now I'm concentrating on this one scenario in particular, so we could assume that for the 'container scenario' with the capacities, that there is always say 20 items in the list.

Comment: I assume you can still change the container object so you can get it's capacity in JavaScript but you can't change the list of capacities. Will post some code you can try out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try someting like this, you'll have to hard code the capacity values for the capacity dropdown but since you can't change that dropdown I think it's the savest way. Unless you want to parse the text and calculate the values (assuming all text values do have values that can be parsed to min and max). In that case you can dynamically create myApp.capacityDropdownValues based on a set of rules that provide min max values for a given text string.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Example</title>
</head>
 <body>
  <select id="selContainers" onChange="myApp.setCap(this);">
   <option value="can" data-capacity="0.33">Can</option>
   <option value="1l" data-capacity="1">One liter bottle</option>
   <option value="2l" data-capacity="2">Two liter bottle</option>
   <option value="bathTub" data-capacity="500">Bath tub</option>
  </select>

 <select id="cap">
   <option>&gt 500ml</option>
   <option>500ml - 1l</option>
   <option>1l - 2l</option>
   <option>&lt 2l</option>
 </select>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myApp = {};
// this part can go in a seperate js file 
myApp.capacityDropdownValues=[
 {min:0,max:0.5}, 
 {min:0.5,max:1}, 
 {min:1,max:2}, 
 {min:2,max:1/0}
];
// sorry for using inline event binding, if you have
// code that can attach/add event listeners that supports multiple browsers
// I'd advice not to use inline binding.
myApp.setCap = function (el){
    var op=el.options[el.selectedIndex],
    capacity=parseFloat(op.getAttribute("data-capacity")),
    i,caps=document.getElementById("cap");
    for(i=0;i<myApp.capacityDropdownValues.length;i++){
        if(myApp.capacityDropdownValues[i].min<=capacity &&
                myApp.capacityDropdownValues[i].max>=capacity){
            caps.selectedIndex=i;
            return;
        }
    }
    console.log("failed");
}
// set the values on load:
myApp.setCap(document.getElementById("selContainers"));
</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Here is some sample code that could dynamically set the capacities object for you and in case there are multiple capacities dropdowns on one page it'll set the capacities object as a property of the select element. Note that values containing &gt won't translate well, as option.value translate to > 5 so you may have to use a regular expression on it to make sure that options containing > and < characters int their value are correcly translated.

```
var myApp = {};
//translations for string to min max values
// if you have values in gallons you can correctly translate that to liters here
myApp.capStringToCapacity={
  '0-500':{min:0,max:0.5},
  '500ml - 1l':{min:0.5,max:1},
  '1l - 2l':{min:1,max:2},
  '2 and up':{min:2,max:1/0}
}
// adds min max values for each option to capacity select
myApp.init=function(){
    var i,j,tmp=[];
    for(i=0;i<myApp.containers.length;i++){
        for(j=0;j<myApp.containers[i].options.length;j++){
            tmp.push(myApp.capStringToCapacity[
              myApp.containers[i].options[j].value]);
        }
        //just add the JS object as property to the select
        myApp.containers[i].capacities=tmp;
    }
}
// set capacity dropdowns to intitialise
myApp.containers=[document.getElementById("cap")];
myApp.init();
```

Comment: Thanks mate; while it isn't a perfect fit for the problem I'm trying to solve, it does give me a few ideas on where I can proceed on this.